# How to nest components under a common header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Trying to understand the basics of `react-router` and I'm a little overwhelmed by the choices and options. I have a `react` + `redux` app built under the general guidelines provided by [Teropa's awesome tutorial](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html).

Essentially all I need is a common `Header` component across all routes; from the Header, users can click a button to change the main component (each view provides different data visualizations). This container should also link to the redux store, and let common data flow down to whichever main component is selected. This strikes me as a super common need, but I cannot find a solid example/tutorial >_<

So far the set up is as follows:

```
// index.jsx --> sets up the redux store and react-router routes

const routes = <Route>
  <Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />
    <IndexRoute to="/summary" />
    <Route path="summary" component={Summary} />
    <Route path="users" component={Users} />
    <Route path="devices" component={Devices} /> 
</Route>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

---

```
// App.jsx --> the main container component

export const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Header {...this.props} />
      {this.props.children}
    </div>;
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

export const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(App);
```

The `Summary`, `Users`, and `Devices` components are just standard dumb React components that populate based upon data flow-downs. At the moment, the error received is that those dumb components do not have access to redux store. However, if I link them directly to the store, they render without the `Header`.

EDIT: removed reference to deprecated `<RouteHandler />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md#routehandler):

> RouteHandler is gone. Router now automatically populates
>   this.props.children of your components based on the active route.

Try with

```js
export const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Header {...this.props} />
      { this.props.children }
    </div>;
  }
});
```

You should also fix your routes so `AppContainer` actually contain the rest of the components (and the `Redirect`):

```js
const routes = <Route component={AppContainer} />
  <Redirect from="/" to="/summary" />
  <Route path="summary" component={Summary} />
  <Route path="users"   component={Users} />
  <Route path="devices" component={Devices} /> 
</Route>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the main components, such as `Summary` are still returning errors indicating that they cannot access the redux store. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to connect every component into the store separately for them to work with it, children or not.

Comment: So I have linked up the `Summary` component to the store, and it renders (woot), but `Header` does not... Seems like `Summary` component is being rendered on its own without regard to the `App` container shell? Sure I could just include `Header` with each component, but the thrust of my question is how to not re-render a common component across different routes.

Comment: You don't need to include `Header` anywhere but in the main class. How do you know `Header` isn't rendering? Did you `console.log` within its `render` method?

Comment: Yes, no `console.log` is showing and there is no `Header` component on the page. Again, I think that I could just add `Header` to the top of every main component, `Summary` `Users` and `Devices`, but I thought there would be a way to not repeat the same component across each view.

Comment: As i said, you don't have to. You're having another problem. Are you correctly importing the `Header` component? What happens if you do `console.log(<Header />)` in the render method?

Comment: I see; apologies for the misunderstanding. Here is what I've gathered: if I navigate to root, `.../#/`, then only `Header` renders; if I navigate to `.../#/summary`, then only `Summary` renders. Console logging `Header` provides the correct information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121687/discussion-between-martriay-and-kwhitejr).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access redux store, then you have to render it first. To do so, you have to do it manually or just use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) library.
Also, it is better to place `Provider` upper level than router.

So your initial code will be like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
   {router}
 </Provider>,
 domRef
);
```

After all your components will have access to store in the `context`. To avoid all mess with it, just use `{ connect } from 'react-redux'`, wrap your components in it and select needed properties.